# Easy rotation in 3D with mouse in Flash rotationXYZ in 2 directions

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, 3d, rotation

I have a Cube which I want to rotate using mouse motion. So if I move my mouse to the left it rotates as if rotationX was increased. When I move right rotationX is increased. Moving Up and Down alters rotationY.

This looks fine as long as you modify only one dimension (either rotationX or rotationY). But if I have already changed rotationX and then try to modify rotationY the results are weird. If rotationX is 180 rotationY effects are reversed. It basically is quite unpredictable and certainly not suitable for user.

I have tried to look around (failed), read about quaternions (couldn't understand), tried some out of blue and very complex trigonometric calculations (made a fool out of myself) and so I am stuck now. I've found this SO question [Best way to translate mouse drag motion into 3d rotation of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/107413/best-way-to-translate-mouse-drag-motion-into-3d-rotation-of-an-object) but it doesn't help me a bit, I can't understand any of the answers, really.

A complete, working solution/algorithm in AS3 would be the best, but some pseudo-code or just clear explanation will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying the rotationY to an already rotated object.  So if you set rotationX to 180, and THEN set rotationY, you are really rotating the object standing "on its head".  If you want to apply both the x and y rotation at the same time, it is best to use a [matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_%28mathematics%29). The link you provided is useful: it explains everything once you understand the concept of matrices.  You should read up on this, especially if you intend to do more 3D in the future.

For now, just have a look at the [Flash manual page for Matrix3D](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/geom/Matrix3D.html).  It should provide all the information and examples you need to get going.

Comment: Yea, I realize that's the cause, I just had hard time wording myself. I know more or less how matrices work theoretically, had it in school, but I can't really grasp the practical implementation that well. Will try again with this Matrix3D though, hopefully this time I can figure it out.

Comment: WOW! *total shock* I can't believe it was THAT easy. And I can't believe I haven't tried this before, not ever noticed this possibility. Turns out all you need is Matrix3D.appendRotation(). I guess back when I was trying it for the first time I assumed modifying rotationXYZ just, kind of, aliases this function. Thanks again for pointing this out to me :D.

Comment: Think of it this way. When you change rotationX, you are rotating the object around *its own* x-axis. What you came here looking for was a way to rotate the object around the *world* x-axis, regardless of where the object's x-axis is. That amounts to your needing to append a rotation to the object's current rotation, which is why appendRotation does what you want, and modifying the parameters doesn't.